# How to make one div fill all horizontal space

Tags: html, css, fill

I'm new to html and css, and while I was creating a page for training, I made one div to fill the top horizontal space.

However I did not have succsess in doing that, and I have no idea why, I tried tweaking the margins, the padding, looked around on the internet and found no solution for my case. I wanna know if it is possible to fill all horizontal space with only one div.

Here is how my code currently is looking:

```css
@charset "UTF-8"; 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron');

body{
  background-color: green;
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
div#page{
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 500px rgb(0,0,0);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
div#pageHead {
    width: 102%;
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    margin: -8px 0px auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageHead">  
  <header></header>
</div>

<div id="page">
  <header>
    this is a test
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a closing header tag in your second div with id page?

Comment: You need to fill which div? there's a problem with a </header> inside the last div

Comment: Add `margin: 0` to `body`. It has a default margin in most browsers (8px in Chrome and FF, not sure about the others), causing the gap between browser frame and page content.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `margin:0` to the `body` tag. You are getting the default margin from the body.

```css
body{
    background-color: green;
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
    margin:0;
}
div#page{
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 500px rgb(0,0,0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
div#pageHead {
    width: 102%;
    background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    margin: -8px 0px auto 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageHead">     
        <header></header>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
            this is a test  
    </div>
```

Comment: I think he means `width:100%` since he said "all horizontal space" not sure tho

Answer (score 0):

First problem, your page div is not valid (closed  tag that is never opened).

For the width, add

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

to reset browser styles.

https://jsfiddle.net/dtz5h9yh/3/

```css
    @charset "UTF-8";   
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron');

    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body{
        background-color: green;
        color: green;
        font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    div#page{
        width: 900px;
        height: 900px;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 500px rgb(0,0,0);
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    }
    div#pageHead {
        width: 102%;
        background-color: rgb(20,20,20);
        height: 70px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
        <div id="pageHead">     
            <header></header>
        </div>

        <div id="page">
            <header>            
                this is a test
            </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
body{ margin :0; background-color: green;color: green; font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif; overflow-x: hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div#page{
    width:100%;
}
```

Also remove the `</header>` from the `div` with `id`"page".
hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

A div by default takes up as much horizontal space as possible. So it is generally as wide as its parent element.

As I understand your problem you are missing the the last few pixels on either side. This is not an issue of the div, but of the body element. The body element has to a default margin.

So you have to set the body margin to 0 (zero). Then you can either not specify a width for the div or give the div a width of 100%.
Then the div should take up the whole horizontal space of the webpage.